# Spring AOP in controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, aop

I have a spring project, and am trying to implements AOP in controllers.

I add these lines in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="homeController" class="package.domain.HomeController" />
<bean id="logAspect" class="package.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
```

My aspect class is this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {


    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Pointcut("execution( * package.web.HomeController.home(..) )")
    public void poincut() {
    }

    @Before("poincut()")
    public void before(){
        System.out.println("before");
    }

    @AfterReturning("poincut()")
    public void after(){
        System.out.println("after");
    }

    @AfterThrowing("poincut()")
    public void AfterThrowing(){
        System.out.println("AfterThrowing");
    }

}
```

and my controller is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home.htm")
    public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ....

        return new ModelAndView("home", "model", model);
    }
```

All likes good, no errors and this message:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method: public void package.aspect.LoggingAspect.before()
DEBUG: org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method: public void package.aspect.LoggingAspect.after()
DEBUG: org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory - Found AspectJ method: public void package.aspect.LoggingAspect.AfterThrowing()
```

If change my pointcut and use the next line it works, but when I choose a controller fails:

```
@Pointcut("execution( * *(..) )")
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What error are you getting? paste trace. Btw, that pointcut is too broad, you should consider restricting it

Comment: Does your package really start with `package`?

Comment: no, is my client package, com.client.project.

Comment: Please show the full  controller class **including package declaration on top** and the same for the aspect. If it works with the generic pointcut, you are making a mistake in package name usage in the pointcut.

Answer (score 0):

If it works for you then go with:

```
@Pointcut("execution( * *(..) )")
```

and restrict your Aspect to your Controller with an additional Pointcut in the same Aspect:

```
@Pointcut("within(@package.web.HomeController *)")
public void controllerBean() {}
```